# How to Import JBLAS Library into Android studio

Tags: java, android, libraries, jblas

This library downloads in a zip format and extracts to an entire folder structure not a jar file.

https://github.com/mikiobraun/jblas-examples/blob/master/src/CG.java

I needed some help in getting this imported into android studio.

Comment: The high performance computing part of Android called RenderScript has predefined BLAS functions: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBLAS.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the [jblas](http://jblas.org/jars/jblas-1.2.4.jar) jar file
2. Copy the jar file to `project/app/libs` directory (create libs folder under the application folder if it doesn't exist).
3. Add the .jar file dependency to your app's `build.gradle` file:

   ```
   dependencies {
     // ... other dependencies
     compile files('libs/jblas-1.2.4.jar')
   }
   ```